Extended Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion Proof
The book "Olympiad Mathematics" has the following proof for Extended Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion,
Extended Eisenstein's Criterion Proof
The proof concludes with the observations,

We conclude that all coefficients $b_1$, $b_2$,...., $b_k$ are divisible by p. Now, $a_{k+1}$ = $b_k$$c_1$ + $b_{k-1}$$c_2$ + $b_{k-2}$$c_2$ + ... ⇒ p|$a_k$+1 but p $\nmid$ ak+1. It follows that degree
of g≥k+1.

My question is, how exactly does the contradiction imply that the factor has to have a degree ≥ k+1? The unextended Eisenstein Criterion has a very similar proof to this,
Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion Proof
But it ends with,

We have p | $a_i$ and by supposition p divides each one of $b_0$,  $b_1$, ..., $b_{i-1}$ ⇒ p | $b_i$$c_0$. But p $\nmid$ $c_0$ ⇒ p | $b_i$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $f(x)$ is irreducible.

here the contradiction implies that $f(x)$ is irreducible. Where is the fundamental difference between both the proofs that results in different observations?
Any help on the topic would be appreciated!

The factor has to have a degree $\geq k+1$ because if it has a degree $l\leq k$ then you have  $a_{k+1}=b_{k} \cdot c_{1}+...+b_{0} \cdot c_{k}$ if $r \geq k$ or $a_{k+1}=b_{k} \cdot c_{1}+...+b_{k-r} \cdot c_{r}$ if $r < k$ (note that if the degree is $l<k$ then you have that $b_{l+1}=...=b_{k}=0$). In both cases all the coeficients $b_{i}$ have index $i \leq k$ and you know that $p | b_{i}$ for all $i \leq k$ so you conclude that $p | a_{k+1}$ and that is a contradiction.
If the factor $g$ has degree $\geq k+1$ then you have $a_{k+1}=b_{k+1}c_{0}+b_{k}c_{1}+...$ and you do not know if $p|b_{k+1}$ so you cannot conclude that $p|a_{k+1}$.

I found the overall structure of the proof a bit unclear. I think it would be best to rephrase it as a proof of contradiction:
Assume that all irreducible factors are of degree $\leq k$. Then there exists one irreducible factor $$g(x) = b_k x^k + \dotsb + b_1x + b_0$$ with $p | b_0$. (Note that $g$ has degree at most $k$, but
we don't necessarily have $b_k \neq 0$.) Write $f(x) = g(x) \cdot h(x)$ and follow the original proof to conclude $p | a_{k+1}$. This is a contradiction, hence there is at least one irreducible factor of $f$ which has degree $> k$.
